# Looping through object in order to get stored array values

Tags: typescript, mongoose

For the project i'm working on I'm passing data through in order to load saved data. When I get the data it comes through like this:

```
{response: 6, plan: {…}}
plan:
items: Array(9)
0: {position: {…}, dimensions: {…}, _id: "5fa95e22d33ebceedf3418e8", id: 0, unitId: 10810, …}
1: {position: {…}, dimensions: {…}, _id: "5fa95e22d33ebceedf3418e9", id: 1, unitId: 10810, …}
2: {position: {…}, dimensions: {…}, _id: "5fa95e22d33ebceedf3418ea", id: 2, unitId: 8874, …}
3: {position: {…}, dimensions: {…}, _id: "5fa95e22d33ebceedf3418eb", id: 3, unitId: 3762, …}
4: {position: {…}, dimensions: {…}, _id: "5fa95e22d33ebceedf3418ec", id: 4, unitId: 3568, …}
5: {position: {…}, dimensions: {…}, _id: "5fa95e22d33ebceedf3418ed", id: 5, unitId: 11000, …}
6: {position: {…}, dimensions: {…}, _id: "5fa95e22d33ebceedf3418ee", id: 6, unitId: 4240, …}
7: {position: {…}, dimensions: {…}, _id: "5fa95e22d33ebceedf3418ef", id: 7, unitId: 11000, …}
8: {position: {…}, dimensions: {…}, _id: "5fa95e22d33ebceedf3418f0", id: 8, unitId: 4240, …}
length: 9
__proto__: Array(0)
room:
depth: 3000
height: 2500
name: "Plan"
width: 3000
__proto__: Object
__v: 0
_id: "5fa95e22d33ebceedf3418e7"
__proto__: Object
response: 6
```

The response: 6 is just what has been manually set to show that the retrieval of the data was successful.

The data comes through under the object data. Now my next task is to loop through the data and get the items in the array items. How is the best way to go about this?

I thought it might be something like:

```
for (i in data) {
console.log(i)
}
```

just as an example but that just outputs "plan". Where am I going wrong and how do I retrieve the array?

Thanks

Comment: Could you not just literally do `data.plan.items` or if it just outputs plan, `data.items`?

Comment: you're absolutely right, thank you

Comment: Will provide this as an Answer instead of a comment so you can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just literally do

```
data.plan.items
```

or if it just outputs plan

```
data.items
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `lodash` library with the `pick`
so something like :

```
_.pick(object, ['items']);
```

see https://lodash.com/docs#pick

Comment: I tried doing console.log(_.pick(data, ['items'])); and all that is outputted is: { }, any idea why it would be outputting as empty?

Comment: I love lodash, but you really don't need a library to solve this issue.